# Redirection loop error after login from a custom post type post

Tags: custom-post-types, loop, wp-login-form

I have created a custom post type called portfolio so such posts have an url like this:

```
mydomain.com/portfolio/post-name/
```

This is fine so far, however i just found I am having a problem with my Wordpress login and i believe this is causing it. I have a login link on every post so if you log in from there it is supposed to redirect you back to the same post page but instead you will get a redirection loop error.

If you look at the URL which Wordpress is trying to redirect to, you will see something like

```
mydomain.com//post-name/
```

notice how "portfolio" is missing from the URL and thats causing the redirection error.

How can i address this problem and have the redirection fixed?

Thank you.

Comment: plugin specific questions are off-topic here, you should ask the plugin author.

Comment: What plugin are you talking about?

Comment: I have no idea, but wordpress do not have a core functionality that lets you login from any page except the login page

Comment: I didnt say you can login on the page, i said i have a LINK to the login page there and thats a core functionality because if people want to post a comment they must log in first.

Comment: If you have a problem with people not being able to comment when comments are restricted to logged-in user then please edit your question and specify explicitly that that is the problem. Seriously your question has almost zero details about your site, what kind of answer do you expect to get with so little details?

Comment: I dont know what any other details you need, the problem is very simple. If you have comments activated there is always a link on every page that says log in to comment, right? If you press that link you are taken to the login page. Log in and you are redirected to the page where the link was. This is regardless of whether you want to post a comment, i never said people cant comment. The issue is that after they log in they are redirected to a loop page.

Comment: Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

How are you currently generating the login URL & handling the redirect?

You should simply be using `wp_loginout` and passing the permalink as the redirect, and let WordPress handle *everything* else:

```
<?php wp_loginout( get_permalink() ) ?>
```

Or for a more custom implementation:

```
<?php if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) : ?>

    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( wp_login_url( get_permalink() ) ) ?>">My custom log in text</a>

<?php endif ?>
```

If you still have issues, disable all plugins. It might also be worth posting the code you use to register the custom post type.

Comment: I just found the fix for my issue. The problem is that the slug for my custom post type was in Japanese and wordpress seems unable to handle that.